# How to crosstab my query so months show in colums in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#time') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #time

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '06/01/2015',
        @StopDate  DATETIME = '09/30/2015'; 

SELECT 
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, dmtrans.DTTDAT), 0) AS 'time',
    dmtrans.DTACRO as 'Loc_Acronym',
    dmloc.DLONAME as 'Location',
    dmdoctr.DDRNPI as 'NPI_Number',
    (COALESCE(dmdoctr.DDRNAME,'')+' '+COALESCE(dmdoctr.DDRTITL,'')) as Provider,
    sum(dmtrans.DTCNTR) as 'Visits',
    sum(RVU.TotalRVU) as 'Total_RVUs',
    (nullif(sum(RVU.TotalRVU),0)/nullif(sum(dmtrans.DTCNTR),0)) as 'Avg_RVU'
INTO
    #time
FROM
    dmtrans
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dmloc ON dmtrans.DTACRO = dmloc.DLOACRO
          AND dmtrans.DTLOC = dmloc.DLONUM
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    cptxref ON dmtrans.DTPROC = cptxref.chcod
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dmdoctr ON dmtrans.DTACRO = dmdoctr.DDRACRO
            AND dmtrans.DTLOC = dmdoctr.DDRLOC
            AND dmtrans.DTRPTDR = dmdoctr.DDRNUM
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    RVU ON cptxref.chmcd1 = RVU.cptcode
        AND RVU.recordname = '2006'
WHERE  
    (dmtrans.DTTTYP = 'C' )
    AND (dmtrans.DTTDAT >= @StartDate)
    AND (dmtrans.DTTDAT <= @StopDate)
    AND (dmtrans.DTMODF <> '*p')
    AND (dmtrans.DTACRO = 'ROS')
GROUP BY 
    dmdoctr.DDRNAME, dmdoctr.DDRNPI, dmtrans.DTTDAT, 
    dmtrans.DTACRO, dmloc.DLONAME, dmdoctr.DDRTITL,
    dmtrans.DTPCPNO, dmtrans.DTRPTDR, dmtrans.DTCNTR         
ORDER BY 
    dmdoctr.DDRNAME, dmtrans.DTACRO, dmtrans.DTTDAT 

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#time2') IS NOT NULL
     DROP TABLE #time2

Select 
    Time,
    Loc_Acronym as 'Loc_Acronym',
    Location as 'Location',
    NPI_Number as NPI_Number,
    Provider as Provider,
    sum(Visits) as 'Visits',
    sum(Total_RVUs) as 'Total_RVUs',
    Round(nullif(sum(Total_RVUs),0)/nullif(sum(Visits),0),2) as 'Avg RVU', 
    DATENAME (M,[time]) as 'Month' into #time2
from 
    #time
group by 
    time, Loc_Acronym, Location, Provider,NPI_Number 
order by 
    Provider

select * 
from #time2
```

So I never work on a crosstab function just learn of it's existence thru a google search. So my current result:

```
Time    Loc_Acronym  Location                    NPI_Number  Provider           Visits  Total_RVUs  Avg RVU Month
2015-06-01 ROS  LOVELACE REG MED CTR- ROSWELL   1538198924  ARRINGTON, ALAN H M.D.    1 4.01    4.010000    June
2015-07-01 ROS  LOVELACE REG MED CTR- ROSWELL   1982631560  ATKINS, ARNOLD M.D.   1   4.01  4.010000    July
2015-09-01 ROS  LOVELACE REG MED CTR- ROSWELL   1982631560  ATKINS, ARNOLD M.D.   1   1.64  1.640000    September
2015-06-01 ROS  LOVELACE REG MED CTR- ROSWELL   NULL    CORRIZ, STEPHEN M D.O.    303   799.92  2.640000    June
2015-07-01 ROS  LOVELACE REG MED CTR- ROSWELL   NULL    CORRIZ, STEPHEN M D.O.    211   571.48  2.710000    July
2015-08-01 ROS  LOVELACE REG MED CTR- ROSWELL   NULL    CORRIZ, STEPHEN M D.O.    235   664.02  2.830000    August
2015-09-01 ROS  LOVELACE REG MED CTR- ROSWELL   NULL    CORRIZ, STEPHEN M D.O.    257   691.11  2.690000    September
```

So my desired result is to keep the current columns but instead of having the months all in one column, I will like to for the months, I'll like to have it in the header row.  How can I do this in my extensive drop tables.

Comment: can you show us how the result you want will looks like?

Comment: Also please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    USE cfsdwhd;
WITH MyCTE 
AS
(
SELECT Dateadd(MONTH, Datediff(MONTH, 0, dmtrans.DTTDAT), 0) AS StartOfMonth,
       dmtrans.DTACRO AS 'Loc_Acronym',
       dmloc.DLONAME AS 'Location',
       dmdoctr.DDRNPI AS 'NPI_Number',
       ( COALESCE(dmdoctr.DDRNAME, '') + ' '
         + COALESCE(dmdoctr.DDRTITL, '') ) AS Provider,
       Sum(dmtrans.DTCNTR) AS 'Visits',
       Sum(RVU.TotalRVU) AS 'Total_RVUs',
       ISNULL(( NULLIF(Sum(RVU.TotalRVU), 0) / NULLIF(Sum(dmtrans.DTCNTR), 0) ), 0.00) AS 'Avg_RVU'
FROM   dmtrans
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dmloc
                    ON dmtrans.DTACRO = dmloc.DLOACRO
                       AND dmtrans.DTLOC = dmloc.DLONUM
       LEFT OUTER JOIN cptxref
                    ON dmtrans.DTPROC = cptxref.chcod
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dmdoctr
                    ON dmtrans.DTACRO = dmdoctr.DDRACRO
                       AND dmtrans.DTLOC = dmdoctr.DDRLOC
                       AND dmtrans.DTRPTDR = dmdoctr.DDRNUM
       LEFT OUTER JOIN RVU
                    ON cptxref.chmcd1 = RVU.cptcode
                       AND RVU.recordname = '2006'
WHERE  ( dmtrans.DTTTYP = 'C' )
AND ( dmtrans.DTTDAT >= '05/01/2015')
AND ( dmtrans.DTTDAT <=  '09/30/2015')
       AND ( dmtrans.DTMODF <> '*p' )
       AND ( dmtrans.DTACRO = 'MOR' )
GROUP  BY  dmtrans.DTACRO,
       dmloc.DLONAME,
       dmdoctr.DDRNPI,
       ( COALESCE(dmdoctr.DDRNAME, '') + ' '
         + COALESCE(dmdoctr.DDRTITL, '') ) ,
          Dateadd(MONTH, Datediff(MONTH, 0, dmtrans.DTTDAT), 0) 
)
SELECT 1 As SortOrder, T1.Loc_Acronym,T1.Location,T1.NPI_Number,T1.Provider,'Sum Of Visits' AS [Values],
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartOfMonth), 0)) = 1 THEN Visits ELSE 0 END) AS 'January',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartOfMonth), 0)) = 2 THEN Visits ELSE 0 END) AS 'February',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartOfMonth), 0)) = 3 THEN Visits ELSE 0 END) AS 'March',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartOfMonth), 0)) = 4 THEN Visits ELSE 0 END) AS 'April',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartOfMonth), 0)) = 5 THEN Visits ELSE 0 END) AS 'May',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartOfMonth), 0)) = 6 THEN Visits ELSE 0 END) AS 'June',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartOfMonth), 0)) = 7 THEN Visits ELSE 0 END) AS 'July',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartOfMonth), 0)) = 8 THEN Visits ELSE 0 END) AS 'August',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartOfMonth), 0)) = 9 THEN Visits ELSE 0 END) AS 'September',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartOfMonth), 0)) = 10 THEN Visits ELSE 0 END) AS 'October',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartOfMonth), 0)) = 11 THEN Visits ELSE 0 END) AS 'November',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartOfMonth), 0)) = 12 THEN Visits ELSE 0 END) AS 'December'
from mycte T1
GROUP BY T1.Loc_Acronym,T1.Location,T1.NPI_Number,T1.Provider
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 As SortOrder, T1.Loc_Acronym,T1.Location,T1.NPI_Number,T1.Provider,'Sum Of Total_RVUs' AS [Values],
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartOfMonth), 0)) = 1 THEN Total_RVUs ELSE 0 END) AS 'January',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartOfMonth), 0)) = 2 THEN Total_RVUs ELSE 0 END) AS 'February',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartOfMonth), 0)) = 3 THEN Total_RVUs ELSE 0 END) AS 'March',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartOfMonth), 0)) = 4 THEN Total_RVUs ELSE 0 END) AS 'April',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartOfMonth), 0)) = 5 THEN Total_RVUs ELSE 0 END) AS 'May',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartOfMonth), 0)) = 6 THEN Total_RVUs ELSE 0 END) AS 'June',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartOfMonth), 0)) = 7 THEN Total_RVUs ELSE 0 END) AS 'July',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartOfMonth), 0)) = 8 THEN Total_RVUs ELSE 0 END) AS 'August',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartOfMonth), 0)) = 9 THEN Total_RVUs ELSE 0 END) AS 'September',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartOfMonth), 0)) = 10 THEN Total_RVUs ELSE 0 END) AS 'October',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartOfMonth), 0)) = 11 THEN Total_RVUs ELSE 0 END) AS 'November',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartOfMonth), 0)) = 12 THEN Total_RVUs ELSE 0 END) AS 'December'
from mycte T1
GROUP BY T1.Loc_Acronym,T1.Location,T1.NPI_Number,T1.Provider
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 As SortOrder, T1.Loc_Acronym,T1.Location,T1.NPI_Number,T1.Provider,'Sum Of Avg RVU' AS [Values],
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartOfMonth), 0)) = 1 THEN Avg_RVU ELSE 0 END) AS 'January',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartOfMonth), 0)) = 2 THEN Avg_RVU ELSE 0 END) AS 'February',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartOfMonth), 0)) = 3 THEN Avg_RVU ELSE 0 END) AS 'March',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartOfMonth), 0)) = 4 THEN Avg_RVU ELSE 0 END) AS 'April',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartOfMonth), 0)) = 5 THEN Avg_RVU ELSE 0 END) AS 'May',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartOfMonth), 0)) = 6 THEN Avg_RVU ELSE 0 END) AS 'June',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartOfMonth), 0)) = 7 THEN Avg_RVU ELSE 0 END) AS 'July',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartOfMonth), 0)) = 8 THEN Avg_RVU ELSE 0 END) AS 'August',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartOfMonth), 0)) = 9 THEN Avg_RVU ELSE 0 END) AS 'September',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartOfMonth), 0)) = 10 THEN Avg_RVU ELSE 0 END) AS 'October',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartOfMonth), 0)) = 11 THEN Avg_RVU ELSE 0 END) AS 'November',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, StartOfMonth), 0)) = 12 THEN Avg_RVU ELSE 0 END) AS 'December'
from mycte T1
GROUP BY T1.Loc_Acronym,T1.Location,T1.NPI_Number,T1.Provider
ORDER  BY Loc_Acronym,Provider,SortOrder}
```

This is what I derived to get the desired result.  Even though I wanted to include a case statement that was dynamic with my where clause dates that only outputted months in that range.  I can live with the result.  Thank you all for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add conditional `CASE/WHEN` for each month to output Month Columns all in one select query. By the way, you did not mention what you want in those month columns. Below I use count but consider any other aggregates.

```
SELECT 
    DATEADD(MONTH, 0, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, dmtrans.DTTDAT)) AS 'time',
    dmtrans.DTACRO as 'Loc_Acronym',
    dmloc.DLONAME as 'Location',
    dmdoctr.DDRNPI as 'NPI_Number',
    (COALESCE(dmdoctr.DDRNAME,'')+' '+COALESCE(dmdoctr.DDRTITL,'')) as Provider,
    sum(dmtrans.DTCNTR) as 'Visits',
    sum(RVU.TotalRVU) as 'Total_RVUs',
    (nullif(sum(RVU.TotalRVU),0)/nullif(sum(dmtrans.DTCNTR),0)) as 'Avg_RVU',    

    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, dmtrans.DTTDAT) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0) As 'January',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, dmtrans.DTTDAT) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0) As 'February',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, dmtrans.DTTDAT) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0) As 'March',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, dmtrans.DTTDAT) = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0) As 'April',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, dmtrans.DTTDAT) = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0) As 'May',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, dmtrans.DTTDAT) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0) As 'June',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, dmtrans.DTTDAT) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0) As 'July',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, dmtrans.DTTDAT) = 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0) As 'August',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, dmtrans.DTTDAT) = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0) As 'September',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, dmtrans.DTTDAT) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0) As 'October',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, dmtrans.DTTDAT) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0) As 'November',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DatePart(MONTH, dmtrans.DTTDAT) = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0) As 'December'

FROM
    dmtrans
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dmloc ON dmtrans.DTACRO = dmloc.DLOACRO
          AND dmtrans.DTLOC = dmloc.DLONUM
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    cptxref ON dmtrans.DTPROC = cptxref.chcod
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dmdoctr ON dmtrans.DTACRO = dmdoctr.DDRACRO
            AND dmtrans.DTLOC = dmdoctr.DDRLOC
            AND dmtrans.DTRPTDR = dmdoctr.DDRNUM
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    RVU ON cptxref.chmcd1 = RVU.cptcode
        AND RVU.recordname = '2006'
WHERE   (dmtrans.DTTTYP = 'C' )
    AND (dmtrans.DTTDAT >= @StartDate)
    AND (dmtrans.DTTDAT <= @StopDate)
    AND (dmtrans.DTMODF <> '*p')
    AND (dmtrans.DTACRO = 'ROS')
GROUP BY 
    dmdoctr.DDRNAME, dmdoctr.DDRNPI, dmtrans.DTTDAT, 
    dmtrans.DTACRO, dmloc.DLONAME, dmdoctr.DDRTITL,
    dmtrans.DTPCPNO, dmtrans.DTRPTDR, dmtrans.DTCNTR         
ORDER BY 
    dmdoctr.DDRNAME, dmtrans.DTACRO, dmtrans.DTTDAT
```

Comment: Thanks for your help two questions do I still have to declare a StartDate and StopDate? I think I do because I have it in the where clause.  Second question once I declare start and stop date , I get a syntax error with case statement with the parenthesis right before the As clause

Comment: Test query without those dates which seem to filter particular set of records. As for syntax issue...hmmm...try using zeros instead of nulls in ELSE clause. Also, I just realized you subtract and then add zero month for `time ` column and arguments were reversed in `DateAdd()` function. Simply take month of the `dttdat` field. See edit.